# list services and store them in array bash

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, awk

I want to list all services from `/etc/init.d/` and grep pattern and store them in array. for instance like below.

```
ls -la /etc/init.d/ | grep example-subs | awk '{ print $9 }'
example-subs-sidekick
example-subs-unicorn
```

and store the strings in array those are returned. but somehow it is not happening. I used below commands.

```
 gawk -F: '{ print $9 }' ls -la /etc/init.d/ | grep example-subs
 gawk -F: '{ print $9 }' "ls -la /etc/init.d/ | grep example-subs"
 gawk -F: '{ print $9 }' 'ls -la /etc/init.d/ | grep example-subs'
 gawk -F: '{ print $9 }' `ls -la /etc/init.d/ | grep example-subs`
 awk '{ print $9 ls -la /etc/init.d/ | grep example-subs }'
 awk '{ print $9 "ls -la /etc/init.d/ | grep example-subs" }'
 awk '{ print $9 `ls -la /etc/init.d/ | grep example-subs` }'
 awk '{ print $9 (ls -la /etc/init.d/ | grep example-subs) }'
 awk '{ print $9 "(ls -la /etc/init.d/ | grep example-subs)" }'
```

But nothing works. Can someone help here.

Comment: Your first command works, why aren't you using that command?

Comment: first command isn't working for me.

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't that a transcript of the command? What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Use your first command as part of the assignment to the array:

```
array=($(ls -a /etc/init.d/ | grep example-subs))
```

You don't need to use `awk`. If you use `ls` instead of `ls -l`, the only thing it prints is the filename.